# Reduce a collection of objects by common field in Java-8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of object `Ob` defined as

```
class Ob {
   private String type;
   private List<String> attire;
   // standard getter and setters

   public Ob (String type){
        this.type=type;
    }

    public Ob addAttrire(String att){
        if(attire == null){
            attire = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        attire.add(att);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I receive objects as

```
[{
"type" : "upper"
attires : [{"t1","t2"}]
},
{
"type" : "upper"
attires : ["t3","t4"]
},
{
"type" : "lower"
attires : ["l1","l2"]
}]
```

which I have to combine as

```
[{
"type" : "upper"
attires : ["t1","t2","t3","t4"]
},{
"type" : "lower"
attires : ["l1","l2"]
}]
```

How can I use stream to do that. Does reduce help?
The stream one can use is

```
List<Ob> coll = new ArrayList<>();


 coll.add(new Ob("a").addAttrire("1").addAttrire("2").addAttrire("3"));
        coll.add(new Ob("a").addAttrire("1").addAttrire("2").addAttrire("3"));
        coll.add(new Ob("a").addAttrire("1").addAttrire("2").addAttrire("3"));
        coll.add(new Ob("b").addAttrire("1").addAttrire("2").addAttrire("3"));
        coll.add(new Ob("b").addAttrire("1").addAttrire("2").addAttrire("3"));
        coll.add(new Ob("b").addAttrire("1").addAttrire("2").addAttrire("3"));



Collection<Ob> values = coll.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Ob::getType, Function.identity(), (o1, o2) -> {
                    o1.getAttire().addAll(o2.getAttire());
                    return o1;
                })).values();
```

Updated the question with solution of Ruben. There is no requirement to remove duplicates, but it can be done using set in Ob for attire. The current solution worked flawlessly.

Comment: About your comment on Rubens answer "*whats the recommended way in such scenario with performance impact*": I think there in no big difference in runtime performance. If the performance turns out to be a problem here I think it's better to rewrite the code using a loop, that would give you more control. I think Rubens solution has an advantage because it's a little shorter and simpler. I think mine has an advantage because it doesn't modify the original `Ob`s and hence is more in a functional style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could collect toMap with a merge function that merges the lists

```
    Collection<Ob> values = coll.stream()
     .collect(toMap(Ob::getType, Function.identity(), (o1, o2) -> {
        o1.getAttire().addAll(o2.getAttire());
        return o1;
    })).values();
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the duplicate attire strings and it returns a collection backed by the `HashMap` instance from `toMap` so I don't think it goes all the way of answering the question. Otherwise it's clever!

Comment: @Lii Removing duplicates might be what _rohit_ wants, but it's nowhere in the question to see, so I have left it out. The code doesn't return a `HashMap`, but a `Collection` (see the `.values()` at the end).

Comment: Oh, there is actually nothing about removing duplicates in the question! I seem to have misread the example earlier, sorry about that. About the collection, what I mean is that the `values` method returns a collection that is *backed* by the map that is created by `toMap`.

Comment: @Ruben Lii Although both the solutions are running absolutely fine, whats the recommended way in such scenario with performance impact. Collecting toMap looks equivalent to grouping, but you guys have any consideration for this.

Comment: @rohit cannot give you more than a 'feeling': my solution uses one collection toMap, and Lii's uses one grouping + an additional stream that creates another one in the map to finally collect toList. From my point of view, mine may perform better, but you should ask an expert or test it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses the `groupingBy` collector and then a separate step that creates a new `Ob` which is the result of merging all the `Ob`s that have the same `type`.

I think Rubens solution has an advantage over this answer because it's a little shorter and simpler. I think this answer has an advantage because it doesn't modify the original `Ob`s and hence is more in a functional style.

```
public static void testTrickyStreamSet() {
    Stream<Ob> s = Stream.of(
        new Ob("a", "1", "2"),
        new Ob("b", "1", "4"),
        new Ob("a", "1", "3"),
        new Ob("b", "1", "5"));

     List<Ob> os = s.collect(groupingBy(o -> o.type))
         .entrySet().stream()
         .map(e -> new Ob(e.getKey(), 
             e.getValue().stream().flatMap(o -> o.attire.stream()).collect(toList())))
         .collect(toList());

     // Prints [<Ob type=a, attire=[1, 2, 3]>, <Ob type=b, attire=[1, 4, 5]>]
     System.out.println(os);
}

public static class Ob {
    public String type;
    public List<String> attire;

    public Ob(String type, String... attire) {
        this.type = type;
        this.attire = Arrays.asList(attire);
    }

    public Ob(String type, List<String> attire) {
        this.type = type;
        this.attire = new ArrayList<>(attire);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<Ob type=" + type + ", attire=" + attire + ">";
    }
}
```